# Airflow AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'update_relative'

Tags: python, airflow

I have my dag as such:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag
from stage import stage_data
from table_async_pg import main

@dag(
dag_id = "data-sync",
schedule_interval = "1 * * * *",
start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 3, 8, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong"),
catchup=False,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=20),
)
def Pipeline():
    a = stage_data()
    b = main()

    a >> b

pipeline = Pipeline()
```

When I don't include `b=main()` and `a>>b` everything works fine. If I include then I get this error:

```
/opt/airflow/dags/airflow_sched.py | Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                      
                                   |   File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskmixin.py", line 230, in set_downstream
                                   |     self._set_relatives(task_or_task_list, upstream=False, edge_modifier=edge_modifier)                 
                                   |   File "/opt/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskmixin.py", line 175, in _set_relatives
                                   |     task_object.update_relative(self, not upstream)                                                     
                                   | AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'update_relative'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `main()` function you're calling in your DAG is a **asyncio coroutine**, which doesn't have the `update_relative` attribute that Airflow expects when setting task dependencies using the `>>` operator.

for fix this problem:

modify the `main()` function to return a `non-coroutine` function or use the `>>` operator with a `non-coroutine` function instead

```py
def Pipeline():
    async def run_main():
        await main()

    a = stage_data()
    b = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_main",
        python_callable=run_main,
    )

    a >> b

pipeline = Pipeline()
```

like this [How to provide an async function in PythonOperator's python_callable in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423101/how-to-provide-an-async-function-in-pythonoperators-python-callable-in-airflow)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `table_async_pg.main` as if it's an Airflow task, but it's not a subclass of Airflow's [BaseOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/baseoperator.py).

While you can assign any value to `b`, this will fail once you try to register `b` as an Airflow task by setting dependencies (`a >> b`). Airflow will try to register the dependency by calling the method `update_relative`, which doesn't exist on `stage_data` and/or `main` because they don't subclass BaseOperator, resulting in an error.